# Swift can't convert the expression's type '()' to type CGRect

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, type-conversion, uiviewanimation

I am new in Swift, and I am trying to animate textField because my keyboard hides it. 
In objective-c this code worked great. 
Here is the editing did begin event function:

```
@IBAction func passwordEditingBegin(sender : UITextField) {
    var movementDistance:Int = 50
    var movementDuration = 0.3

    UIView.beginAnimations("anim", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(movementDuration)



    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movementDistance)
                    //^ Can't convert the expressions type '()' to type CGFloat
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`movementDistance` is an `Int`, it must be a `CGFLoat` for `CGRectOffset`.

```
var movementDistance:CGFloat = 50
```

Objective-C automatically promoted variables, Swift does not.

Definition of `CGRectOffset`

```
func CGRectOffset(rect: CGRect, dx: CGFloat, dy: CGFloat) -> CGRect
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, here is the solution:

```
@IBAction func passwordEditingBegin(sender : UITextField) {
    var movementDistance:Float = -50 // changed from Int to Float
    var movementDuration = 0.3

    UIView.beginAnimations("anim", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(movementDuration)

    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movementDistance)

    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```